# How should I setup the PIC's LCDREF register?

Tags: pic, lcd, driver

I am using PIC16F1946. It has a LCD driver module in it. I read the datasheet and it mentions LCDREF register (Section 27-3 in the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41414C.pdf)). I cannot find useful info on how to set it up?

Could anyone help me out here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet looks to have all the info you need, but there is also an [app note](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en551178) with example code on the chips page at Microchip that might help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the whole datasheet section for the LCD, which is section 27 starting on page 335 and is 35 pages long.  You apparently don't understand some background about how LCDs are driven in general and this hardware module in particular, else the well written description of the LCDREF register in section 27-3 on page 339 would make sense.

Read *all* the data sheet section on the LCD.  Don't try to get away with reading just what you think you need.  You should always want to understand the whole hardware module before attempting to use it in any particular mode.

Comment: If i knew it in depth i wouldn't be asking for help, but will be helping someone. And yes I have read those sections like 5 times and i understand how to configure LCDCON,LCDPS and LCDSEx registers. I am not sure on LCDIRE, LCDIRS and LCDIRI bits.

Comment: @Rashid - Olin may come across a little harsh, but he tells it like it is.  I agree that your problem is that you don't understand how LCDs work.  If you've read the datasheet, and don't understand the terminology, look it up.  Asking a question about LCD contrast and biasing would probably be more appropriate, and get you the information that you really need.  Using example code and setting sensible defaults may make it work for now, but you haven't addressed your core problem.

Answer (score 1):

That register sets up the LCD bias voltages.  As a first test, you can simply set it to 0x80 and try it out.  For most uses that will work just fine.  If you need to customize your LCD driving voltages and currents, you will need to delve further into that register (check out figure 27-3 for how it affects the bias voltages), but for most simple situations, 0x80 will provide reasonable biasing for most LCDs.